# howto insert this json(post) into mariadb?

Tags: node.js, json, mariadb

{"11":{"counts":"0","endtimes":"18:26:36","ids":"NONE","starttimes":"18:26:05","dates":"2021-05-27 18:26:36","machineids":"10002","nums":11,"entiretimes":"00:00:31"},"12":{"counts":"14","endtimes":"18:29:09","ids":"NONE","starttimes":"18:27:4
3","dates":"2021-05-27 18:29:09","machineids":"10002","nums":12,"entiretimes":"00:01:26"},"13":{"counts":"16","endtimes":"18:32:06","ids":"NONE","starttimes":"18:30:28","dates":"2021-05-27 18:32:06","machineids":"10002","nums":13,"entiretimes":"00:00:22"}

i got this data post.
but i don't know this data to maria db. nodejs(express)

...... this situation ......

insert into countdata ?????? ....value(body?????)

Comment: I think it would help understand your problem a little more if you added a little more explanation of what you're trying to do (just in general). Also, you might find this MariaDB webinar (on JSON) useful -> https://go.mariadb.com/JSON-Relational-How-to-use-hybrid-data-models-2019-11-12.html. As well as this (React.js/Node.js) sample app -> https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/dev-example-places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the name of the table you are wanting to insert data into is called `countdata`, that it contains a JSON column called `attr`, and the JSON payload you've sent to your Node.js POST method is held in a variable called `data`, you can use the MariaDB Node.js Connector to insert data into MariaDB like...

```js
await conn.query("insert into countdata (attr) values (?)", [data]);
```

where `conn` is a Connection object obtained from the MariaDB Connector/Node.js

And if you'd like to ... you can use the JSON_COMPACT function, which removes all unnecessary spaces so the JSON document is as short as possible.

```js
await conn.query("insert into countdata (attr) values (json_compact(?))", [data]);
```

Here is a sample app that uses MariaDB Connector/Node.js with various MariaDB JSON functions: https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/dev-example-places

Comment: thank you so much robert! i solved that... DATA -> JSON.parSe(data) -> i, i data.length,i++ , data[i].counts.....endtimes . ->ejs!